# Using autoref with my own label to my own new environment

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, environments, mdframed, labels

I defined my own environment. Now I want to refer to my environment with autoref. But autoref should refer with my own defined name. But I don't know how to do this. Could someone help me?

My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} %Boxen mit Seitenumbruch
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
%
%
\newmdenv[tikzsetting={fill=blue!10},roundcorner=10pt,innerbottommargin=15pt, shadow=true,shadowsize=6pt,shadowcolor=gray,linewidth=8pt,needspace=50pt ]{myshadowbox}
%
%
\newenvironment{mybox}[1]{\begin{myshadowbox}\textbf{#1}}{\end{myshadowbox}}
%
%
\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\begin{mybox}{TestBOX}\label{lablel1}
TEST
\end{mybox}

\section{Section1}
Test
\autoref{lablel1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your environment has no anchor for any labels. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: When I now use \autoref, then comes something like "Section 0.1" (or in German "Abschnitt0.1"). Because this is my Theory-Box, I want instead of "Section 0.1" something like "Theory-Box 0.1".

Comment: You need to define a counter variable (with the `\newcounter` command), execute `\refstepcounter` on that variable when you custom environment is entered, provide a `\label` to the instance(s) of the environment you'd like to cross-reference, and tell `hyperref` what the name should be of cross-referenced instances of your environment.

Comment: Use `\newmdtheoremenv` and everything will work

Comment: With Mico's solution I got it.

Comment: With Mico's solution I got it.
Do you know how to set the counter like the ones for equations? Now the Box starts with 1 and in Section 4 is the next Box and it would be Box 2 than. But I would like to have  Box 1.2. 
Or to start in every Section with a new counter would also be ok.

I dont unterstand:
 \newmdtheoremenv
 I found it not in the mdframed documentation nor in the ntheorem documentation.

Big thanks so far to everybody.

Comment: Use the optional argument of `\newcounter`, set it to either `chapter` or `section`. See http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX-Wörterbuch:_newcounter

Comment: Oh, thanks. This is so easy. I should have found it by my own...